# on click, reduce countdown with 1 and so something, when countdown reaches 0 open window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

> **If the downvoters could leave a reason. That'd be great.**

Lets say I have a value of 10 on my web page, and a button.

Every time a user clicks on this button, I want to have a visual indication of the value decreasing by 1.

When value is 0 (after 10 clicks) it will hide a div, and show another one.

However when clicking the button, not only the counter needs to reduce by 1 but it also needs to open a window. (It's the same window every click)

On every click I'd also like to change style="width:x%"`` with 10-20-30% and so forth. (But with a delay of 5 seconds)

Does anyone have an idea on how to do all of this, without going overboard on the amount of code.

Here the steps:

- Click button
- Window opens
- Counter goes from 10 to 9
- After 5 seconds have passed the progress bar's style switches to
  `width: 10%;`

...

Counter reaches 0:

- Hide div X (fadeout)
- Show div X

source code:

```
function countdown() {
    var i = document.getElementById('counter');
    if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
        //hide div
        //show div
    }
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
    window.open("");
    //change loader
}
```

Comment: is this a school project?

Comment: I am not in school... Haven't been for 4 years now. Just a side project

Comment: setInterval is your friend here.

Comment: No source code = nothing to work with or do you expect people to build it all for you? Have you made any attempt(s) of doing this yourself? If so I would recommend editing your question and adding some source code for people to work with **and** display your attempt(s), explain why you think your attempt(s) don't work as intended. If you cannot display source code/attempt(s) then I wish you the very best with your wish list.  *No source code > No attempts will result in users downvoting you.*

Comment: This isn't enough to work with, where is the related html to go with your javascript function? Also `hide div` / `show div` What div is being shown/hidden. If you cannot explain your problem in detail or provide enough information/source for others work with then I see no point in making any attempt to help you. You need to help us understand your problem for us to help you. From what I see, you have made no attempt to hide/show any div element. Maybe do some research to get you started? Submitting a question that needs multiple thing adding (not fixing) but adding = us doing the work for you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is to help each other with problems, your problem is you haven't started your todo list. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how is this not enough information, I clearly stated what I want the code to do, the html I have is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: So we don't need to know the name/class/id of the progress bar to change the css? How can you use javascript to change an element without knowing the id/class of it? Or the parent id/class... You clearly expect others to do the work for you. I'm only interested in helping those who want to learn from the answers and make some attempt before asking. I wish you the very best with your project.  *Maybe hire a developer?*

Comment: @Snowlav how is the HTML irrelevant? You're modifying and interacting with it. From what you've posted it sounds like there's a counter, a progress bar, a button and a modal window.To do what you want there will need to be hooks (CSS id/class) in the HTML for the JavaScript to attach events to and such.

Comment: Those can all be variables, how can I learn more from having people in-cooperate the already existing ids / classes as opposed to have to alter the code myself to have it fit my project. Wouldn't I learn more from the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is maybe the solution you wanted:

```
function countdown() {
  var i = document.getElementById('counter');
  if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
    $("#counter").fadeout();
    i.innerHTML =10;
    i.style.width="100%";
    $("#counter").fadein(10);
  } else {
    i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
    setTimeout(function(){
      var i = document.getElementById('counter');
      i.style.width="10%";
      i.innerHTML="1";
    },5000)
  }
  var msg = window.open("", "Window name", "width=200, height=100");
  msg.document.write("Some HTML");
}
```

You have to add jquery in the html head!
Leave a comment if the code doesn't help.

Comment: This comes very close to what I had in mind, with some tweaking I got it to function to my taste, thanks :)